# Semitrasparent layer on MediaPlayer

Tags: android, video

How can i set a semitrasparent layer on my video player (MediaPlayer) programmatically ?
I need to do this in onTouch() event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is, for example, in a `FrameLayout`, you can put an `ImageView` over it, and alter the visibility from code (`.setVisibility()`)